# Why eleventy front matter in index.md goes into index.html

Tags: eleventy

I try to go through [Eleventy Guide](https://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-with-eleventy/) and stuck on step "Render Your First Page".

Project structure:
[image]

**package.json**
[image]

**.eleventy.js**

[image]

**index.md**

[image]

**_includes/page.njk**

[image]

I start eleventy with `npx eleventy --serve`

[image]

and get build/index.html:

[image]

In browser:
[image]

**What did I do wrong?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the bug is about, but I resolved it.
If I copy/past front matter from [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-with-eleventy/):

```
‐‐‐
title: 11ty starter site
description: This is a demonstration website generated using the 11ty static site generator.
layout: page.njk
‐‐‐
```

it don't have any syntax highlighting:
[image]

But when I clear `index.md`  front matter and write it by yourself, it looks different, it has syntax highlighting now.

[image]

I think problem is `---`  symbols. It looks the same, but it's no 
[image]